# How many AA batteries can you charge at once?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Using a standard 120V @ 15A, how many AA can I charge at once? The AA is 1.5V @ 3Ah. What I am trying to figure out is how to charge a bunch of AA batteries that are connected together in series at once.

Comment: more than one ..

Comment: that would be a lot of batteries in series, with a current limiter which vastly depends on the battery chemistry. I think this method makes series batteries unmanageble in case of balancing.

Comment: I think you're approaching this very strangely. Instead of having a use case for which you need batteries, you have a power supply and design your battery pack for that. Instead of asking this very strange [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), you should explain what you're trying to *achieve* with all this. It's certainly not "connecting as many AA batteries in series to win the Guiness world record for most AA batteries charged in series for no good reason".

Comment: With 120 V * 15 A = 1800 W input available and a resonable charge current of C/2 = 1500 mA, you end up with a theoretical max 800 AA bateries charged at once, given 100 % efficiency. In real life, I would expect 500 of them is a more resonable figure.

Comment: Your question suggests that you're thinking about connecting lots of cells in series and connecting them **directly** (no transformer) to 120 V mains voltage. I hope that's **not** what you intend to do as that means that all the batteries will have **mains live voltage** on them so when you touch them, you get an electrical shock. Also, if **only one** of the connections between the batteries fails (is not a good connection) there will be 120 V across that point. That can result in sparks and burned contacts. All in all: **this is NOT a good idea**.

Comment: You can't charge AA batteries directly off the mains. So you need a charging circuit, and depending on how it is designed it could charge any number of cells. How many cells do you have, and why do you want to charge them all at once in series?

Comment: Depends on how fast (at what current) you want to charge them. Unless you specify that, you can charge infinitely many batteries and it will take infinitely long to charge them, as long as total mains current for your 15A circuit is not exceeded. 15A at 120V is 1800  watts. But you need a charger, those are not directly charged from 120 VAC.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie there's also the obvious problem that mains power is AC.

Comment: @user253751 A simple rectifier solves that, there would need to be some current limiting circuit as well. But for these, solutions exist. The issues I pointed out are much more fundamental and unsolvable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an XY problem

Answer (score 1):

> Using a standard 120V @ 15A, how many AA can I charge at once

120V @ 15A is 1800 W.

1.5V @ 3Ah is 4.5 Wh, or 16200 Joules.

16200 J / 1800 W is 9 seconds. Theoretically, you have enough power to fully charge a battery in 9 seconds (**don't do this**). And then you can only charge one battery at a time.

But the battery will explode if you try to charge it in 9 seconds. The energy needs to be delivered slowly over a long time - more like 2 hours.

2 hours / 9 seconds = 800. If you charge 800 batteries at the same time, each one gets 2.25 W and they take 2 hours to charge.

But wait! If you deliberately slow down the charging - maybe 4 hours - you can charge twice as many batteries at once, so 1600. If you make it 8 hours, you can charge 3200 at once. And so on. Why not make it take a week (168 hours), and you can charge 67200 batteries at once? Or even a year (8760 hours) and you can charge 3504000 batteries at once? You can charge as many batteries as you want, from the same power source, if you make the charging slow enough.

These are all theoretical ideal numbers. In reality, not all the power will go to the batteries, as the charger will make some heat. And not all the power that goes into the batteries will charge them, as the batteries make some heat.

> What I am trying to figure out is how to charge a bunch of AA batteries that are connected together in series at once.

The question you have asked is completely useless for that purpose. If you want to know how to charge a battery then ask how to charge a battery - don't ask how many batteries you can theoretically charge.

Answer (score 0):

120/1.5= 80 batteries in series. By 120 V, i mean 120 V DC with minimum ripple if possible. Also, several problem will arise with this particularly having a unbalanced charge in all the batteries. What you can do however is use a switch, first charge in parallel and then supply in series. With this you can charge almost infinite batteries but then the charging time will also be infinite. Why is this so? Because that maximum 15A current would be divided for each battery you would add. so for 5 batteries in parallel that would be 15/5= 3 amps. For 50 batteries it would be 0.3 amps and so on. Now, another problem each parralel circuit has a potential of 120V and a single 1.5V battery is sure to get blown up unless there is a over-voltage protection circuitry (which i doubt AA's have).

Comment: I am missing alot of things in my answer and to be honest the generality of the question only begs for this to happen.